# C: Can I do static intialization of an array with both size and address?

Tags: arrays, c, static, initialization

(How) can I initialize a C array by specifying the address and still the number of elements ("size") at the same time?

### Static initialization with element count:

```
static int foo[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

This is nice because a human reader, a linter and the compiler know the number of array elements.

### Static initialization with address:

```
static int* foo = (int*)address_of_foo;
```

This is not so nice because the number of elements is not known.

### Static initialization with element count and address?

Consider having a large array stored somewhere else (e.g. in a non source code file or in a different hardware register on an embedded system). I know the address of this array and I also know the size, but I want to have all advantages of having the size specified in the code. Is this possible somehow? The following code

```
static int foo[4] = (int*) address_of_foo;
```

fails to compile, e.g. with this error: `error: array initializer must be an initializer list`.

Is there a solution or is this not supported by C compilers?

Comment: You can't assign an address of an array. Or of any other variable. Not by the means of compiler. You can use some compiler extensions and/or some linker magic (such as placing variables in specific sections with known addresses).

Comment: C doesn't care what the length of a 1D array is. As ever, if you know its length, you can use that in your code to stay within bounds, and the `int*` pointer will do the job. If you want the info to be in one place, you can use a `struct` to contain the pointer and the data length.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I know that the `inf*` pointer will do the job, but it is not nice. I was looking for a better solution in terms of *knowing important info while reading the code*.

Comment: Isn't `struct data { int *address; size_t elements; } rec = { (int*)0xDEADBEEF, 42 };` all in one place and readable?

Comment: "I want to have all advantages of having the size specified in the code": What advantages are those, specifically?  For instance, are you looking for `sizeof(foo)` to return `4 * sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Two advantages I'd like to have:
1. For the human reader not having to look it up in the comment of where the variable came from.
2. For the compiler to make sure that access to error out if I try to access `foo[95]`.
The sizeof operator would be nice too, but not important in this case.

Comment: The compiler does not check the array bounds, except when initialising at the point of definition. That is left to the programmer to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a pointer to array like this:

```
/* casting to (void *) since i am to lazy to figure out the correct casting */
static int (*foo)[4] = (void *) address_of_foo;
```

The downsize to this, is that you have to dereference the pointer when using array elements:

```
(*foo)[2] =42;
/* A good compiler should hopefully give you a warning on this: */
(*foo)[95] = 42;
```

If you prefer, you could hide the dereferencing behind a `#define`:

```
static int (*foo_ptr)[4] = (void *) address_of_foo;
#define foo (*foo_ptr)

foo[2]=42;
```

Personally I find both solutions a little bit "hackish", so I wouldn't use them myself